# Find the total count of all related records in child records using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I am trying to find the count of records in a related table, however the parent table contains a recursive relationship and I can only seem to get the related count for records that are at the bottom of the tree, and I need the total of all the records related to the current record as well as it's children.

I have tried using common table expressions to do this, however whenever I add the count function into the query I get an error saying that 'GROUP BY, HAVING, or aggregate functions are not allowed in the recursive part of a recursive common table expression'.

I have been scratching my head over this for quite a while now and will probably end up writing a C# function to do this instead but I was wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to achive this in SQL.

Thanks

Comment: I am pretty sure it is possible with plain SQL but to be able to help, at a minimum, you should post a schema definition and preferably some testdata and required results.

Answer (score 1):

Try `select count(*) from cte` where the CTE defines the recursive relationship but does not attempt any aggregation itself.